# Creating SSRS report with Active Directory data

Tags: c#, t-sql, active-directory, ssrs-2008

I have to create a SSRS report with data from Active Directory. I have gone through few blogs which suggested using ADSI and SSIS to perform this. I do not have permissions to create SQL table so cannot use SSIS option. Any other suggestions on extracting Active Directory data?

Comment: Can you create linked server?

Comment: No I cannot create linked server.

Answer (score 2):

Without a linked server, perhaps you can use Directory services and a simple app.

Make a visual studio program with a *System.DirectoryServices* reference and proper permissions.

Pull the data you want from the server and dump it into an xml and save it in a place the report services can reach.  Use the xml to build the report.

Run the app regularly on a schedule to update the xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nathan.